# Upgraded to Cordovo 2.2.0 and now push notifications stopped working on lock screen (IOS)

Tags: ios, push-notification, cordova

I upgraded to cordova 2.2.0 and now my pushwoosh push notifications stopped working. They only work when the iphone is unlocked?

When I send out a push... nothing happens on the ios device.. until I unlock the screen (then the pushes come through).

I have verified that the notifications settings in the 
iPhone's Settings - Notifications - MYAPP - "View in Lock Screen" = on...

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

That's very strage. I have tried Pushwoosh with Cordova 2.2.0 and it works fine and notification displays on the lock screen with no problem.

If the screen is locked for a while then the phone may go into the deep sleep mode (to save the battery) disabling all networking operations, and push notifications will be delivered only when then phone will be unlocked. But that's not the case if you locked the screen just a minute ago. In this case I will suggest doing clean reinstall of the app and rebooting the phone. Sometimes it helps, especially if you have been changing push notifications settings.